# need to read files by their extensions

Tags: c#, excel, listview, text

I am looking to read only one file type into my listview, so if the file ends in .txt it should only read in the .txt file and the same goes for csv and excel files.

```
    public void doexcel()
    {
        OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + textBox_Choose.Text +
                              ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';");

        string name; name = "";
        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * from [" + "Sheet1$" + "]", cnn);
        cnn.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row[0].ToString());
            for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                item.SubItems.Add(row[i].ToString());
            }
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }




    public void dotxt()
    {

        string filepath = textBox_Choose.Text;
        FileStream yaNew = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader yaRead = new StreamReader(yaNew);
        string yaView = yaRead.ReadToEnd();


        yaRead.Close();
        yaNew.Close();
        String[] yaArray = yaView.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
        foreach (string ya in yaArray)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(ya);
        }

    }        


    private void button_Choose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Call the OpenFileDialog Object and name it 
        OpenFileDialog explore = new OpenFileDialog();

        //Set the directory path 
        explore.InitialDirectory = @"c:\MyProject";

        //set the file types 
        explore.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        explore.FilterIndex = 2;
        explore.RestoreDirectory = true;


        //show result in the textbox 
        if (explore.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox_Choose.Text = explore.FileName;
        }
```

Comment: What is your question? You've provided no explanation for the code you've posted. Is there some problem you have with the code? What is it? Where? Have you done any debugging whatsoever?

Comment: My question is how do do it :) do i use a loop like.... if(Path.Fileextesion == ".txt")

Comment: sorry I dont really know how to use this site, im a newb, the code is fine only when i click the load file button it reads the .txt file fine , then it reads the excel file in characters, I would like  for it to read the file extension, so if the file ends in .txt it will only read that file into the listview, thanks

Comment: @user2703960, this has been flagged up.  Please edit your question to clearly identify a specific problem you need help with.  In its current state, your question will attract forced closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the extension of your file with System.IO.Path.GetExtension

In your code, it would be:

```
string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(textBox_Choose.Text);
if (extension == ".txt")
    dotxt();
else if(extension == ".csv")
    doexcel();
else
{
    //deal with an unexpected case
}
```

Comment: It's still shown the both files when I select the .xlxs file, Thanks very much for your help :)

Comment: So, you just want to clear the ListView and show only onw file? Is that it?

Comment: No for some reason if i read the xlxs file it reads fine on its own, then when I read the .txt file it reads it fine but also try's to read the xlxs file as a txt file, i need that to stop and just read the text file rather than reading the both, Thanks I appreciate it

Comment: Where do you call dotxt() and doexcel() methods and what is the value of textBox_Choose.Text when you do?

Comment: Im sorry but this is my first application I dont really know what you mean

Comment: Hm, ok. Can you post the whole code, then? It will be easier to tell you.

Comment: the Code is to big to post in the comment and I really dont know how to use this website, Thank you for your patience

Comment: You can edit your own question to illustrate better your problem. The option is below the tags you set. (share | edit | flag )

Comment: its still to big, its over 3000 characters :(

Answer (score 0):

you can get the extention with this code and do your logic

string ext = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf('.'));